# How to generate an URL link to each individual Sheet in my Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know if it's possible to use a formula or a script to capture the URL of each tab in Google Sheets?

For instance, I have 3 Google worksheets that are all connected, and each one has 150 individual tabs. I want to create a unique link to each of the tabs without having to copy and paste each URL onto the spreadsheet.

How can I generate an URL link to each individual Sheet in my Spreadsheet with either Apps Script or Google Sheet formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) you can simply take of of the functions [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl) and [getSheetId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetid) to concatenate them with `#gid=` and create a simple link to that specific sheet.

In the following example with self-explained comments I iterate over all the sheets to get an array of links to every single sheet in your Spreadsheet:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get SpreadsheetUrl
  var sheetUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl();
  // Get all the sheets
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  // Create array to store all the links
  var links = [];
  // For each sheet in sheets add an array element to our array with the 
  // string of the URL for that sheet
  sheets.forEach(sheet=>links.push(sheetUrl+'#gid='+sheet.getSheetId()));

  Logger.log(links);
}
```